# Variance and covariance of a circle's coordinates

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, covariance

Given a circle of radius 1 with uniform distribution, let X and Y be the random variables that associate a point $(x,y)$ to $x$ and $y$ respectively. Find the expected value of X, $E(X)$, its variance $Var(X)$ and the covariance $cov(X,Y)$.

I have tried solving this problem, but I don't know if I'm doing it right. My attempt is as follows:

Knowing that the area of the circle is $\pi$, and supposing my circle is centered in the origin I could define:
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1/\pi & \text{if } x^2+y^2\leq 1\\
            0 & \text{if } x^2 + y^2>1
\end{cases}
$$
Using that calculate $p_X(x)$
$$
p_{X}(x) = \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{1}{\pi}dy = \frac{y}{\pi}\Big|_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi} + \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$

For the expected value I get:
$$
E[X]  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp_X(x)dx = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2}{\pi}x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = 0
$$
For the variance I get:
$$
Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = E[X^2] = \int_{-1}^{1}x^2p_X(x)dx = \int_{-1}^{1}x^2\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}
$$
And finally, for the covariance:
$$
cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = E[XY] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xy\cdot p_{X,Y}dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}xy\cdot p_{X,Y}dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1}y\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\frac{1}{\pi}dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1} y\left( \frac{x^2}{2\pi}\Big|_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right) dy = \int_{-1}^{1}y\left(0\right) = 0
$$

I found it a little weird getting these result such as the ones in the variance and covariance. I got $cov(X,Y)=0$ even though $X$ and $Y$ are definitely not independent (I know that if $cov(X,Y)=0$ it doesn't necessarily imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but I still can't get why this happens or if it's correct at all). As for the remaining results, I'm just starting with this topic, so I still don't know if I'm doing these exercises correctly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: your calculations seems right, I dont see any mistake

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks a lot for checking it out!

Comment: A circle is not a disk.  i.e. you should not be counting the interior.

Comment: @DougM Disk or circle does not matter. If a scatter plot of randomly drawn $X,Y$ is rotationally invariant around the origin the correlation being the regression coefficient of a linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$ can be nothing but zero.

Comment: @KurtG. It matters in the calculation of $Var(X)$ but not in the cacluation of $E[X]$ or $COV[X,Y]$

Comment: @DougM So far I agree. Is it weird -as OP wrote- that cov is zero ? Do we have to go through calculations at all ?

Comment: I think [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/can-somebody-illustrate-how-there-can-be-dependence-and-zero-covariance) explains it by far in the best way.

Comment: @KurtG. I don't think it is weird.  When I think of the covariance, I think if I were to plot the data in a scatter-plot, what would be the slope of the minimum least squares line?  I suppose this would be the regression coefficient and not the covariance.  But zero regression coefficient implies zero correlation.    If the data plot is a disk or a circle,  there is no reason for this line to have any slope.  This is very much an applied / statistical way of thinking about it compared to the symmetry argument.  Nonetheless, we get to the same place.

Comment: @DougM +1. Would you fancy writing a better answer than Flavien below?